# APFS - Other volumes in container problem

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, disk-space, apfs

I ran into issues with my Macbook Pro running High Sierra 10.13.4.

The problem is that `Other volumes in container` metric are showing over `176 GB` of space taken and I am not able to reclaim it back. I am not running Time Machine on this computer.

[image]

The `diskutil apfs list` command is showing me following result:

[image]

Pretty much the `Capacity In Use By Volumes` is showing `225.4 GB`, but the sum of listed volumes is ~`51 GB`.

I have no idea where my `176 GB` of disk space is.

Comment: Any luck in any other venues?